# Change variable group name dynamically in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm trying to change the variable group in azure devops pipeline using the code below. I don't run into any errors but, at the same time it does not work as I intend it to be working. I have tried a few other ways but none seem to work. Do you have any pointers where I'm going wrong.

***build.yaml***

```
variables:
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Production') }}:
  - group: Production
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Staging') }}:
  - group: Staging
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Test') }}:
  - group: Test
- ${{ if eq('$(env)', 'Development') }}:
  - group: Development
```

Comment: It would help you to understand the different syntaxes for referencing variables. I strongly recommend reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didnt try this, but wouldn't it be better to do this instead:

```
variables:
- group: ${{ parameters.env }}
```

Comment: If I were to use parameters this works just fine. But, how do I make it work with the variables.

Comment: please raise a new question for this :) you can link it in the comments, i'll take a closer look

Comment: Yes, done. Here's the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75654104/change-variable-group-name-dynamically-in-azure-devops-using-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference it properly:

```
parameters:
  - name: env
    type: string
    default: Production
    values:
      - Production
      - Staging
      - Test
      - Development

variables:
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'Production') }}:
    - group: Production
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'Staging') }}:
    - group: Staging
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'Test') }}:
    - group: Test
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.env, 'Development') }}:
    - group: Development
```

In case `env` is variable - you need to use `variables.env`.

More info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops